# Can't access Roles in JWT Token .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, keycloak

I have an application made with .NET Core API, Keycloak and JWT Token.

The older version of Keycloak that I've been using so far, when it created the JWT Token it wrote the roles here on payload:

```
{
    "user_roles": [
        "offline_access",
        "uma_authorization",
        "admin",
        "create-realm"
  ]
}
```

But now after I updated it, it's writing the roles here on payload:

```
{
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "create-realm",
      "teacher",
      "offline_access",
      "admin",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
}
```

And I need to know how to change this old code to the new one, to tell that don't look at `user_roles`, but do look at `realm_access` then to `roles`.

```
public void AddAuthorization(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "admin"));
        options.AddPolicy("Teacher", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "teacher"));
        options.AddPolicy("Pupil", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "pupil"));
        options.AddPolicy(
            "AdminOrTeacher",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(
                context => context.User.HasClaim(claim =>
                               claim.Type == "user_roles" && (claim.Value == "admin" || claim.Value == "teacher")
                          ))
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: nested claims are not supported with the microsoft identity model used there (`Claims` class having no sub-claims option/feature). Use the flat flat (key-value) structure from the first segment

Answer (score 22):

The following code will transform "realm_access.roles"-claim (JWT Token) from Keycloak (v4.7.0) into Microsoft Identity Model role-claims:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
    ...
}

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        // flatten realm_access because Microsoft identity model doesn't support nested claims
        // by map it to Microsoft identity model, because automatic JWT bearer token mapping already processed here
        if (claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated && claimsIdentity.HasClaim((claim) => claim.Type == "realm_access"))
        {
            var realmAccessClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst((claim) => claim.Type == "realm_access");
            var realmAccessAsDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(realmAccessClaim.Value);
            if (realmAccessAsDict["roles"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var role in realmAccessAsDict["roles"])
                {
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about what your code does

Answer (score 4):

For any future readers - you can parse any claim value from JWT with *RequireAssertion* method.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy =>
   policy.RequireAssertion(c =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(c.User?.FindFirst((claim) => claim.Type == "realm_access")?.Value ?? "{}")
             .FirstOrDefault().Value?.Any(v => v == "admin") ?? false)));
```