# Keycloak user roles angular and .net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, keycloak

i have a Keycloak question. I want to add user roles to my Angular (Client) / .net core (Backend) Application. I have no experience, so I looked at this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@xavier.hahn/adding-authorization-to-asp-net-core-app-using-keycloak-c6c96ee0e655

My client send the token to the backend. In the backend I add the [Authorize] attribute to my Controller class. If I send a get to the backend, the authorization process works fine I get the data. But, if I set the [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")] to the controller method I get a 403 error:

```
Response {_body: "", status: 403, ok: false, statusText: "Forbidden", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(5), _normalizedNames: Map(5)}
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:64336/api/SampleData/authorization"
_body: ""
__proto__: Body
```

In the access token the user_roles are set:

```
 "user_roles": [
        "uma_protection",
        "Administrators",
        "Users"
      ],
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong, or does someone know another tutorial?

Many Thanks

Keycloack 4.8.3.

.net core 2.2

Angular 7

Comment: If the user roles are nested under realm_access please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702555/cant-access-roles-in-jwt-token-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

you need to verify that your settings are correct.

In the Startup file:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
      options.AddPolicy("MyPolice", policy => policy.RequireClaim("myMapper", "MyRole"));
 });
```

In the Controller file:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "myPolicy")]
public ActionResult Protect()
{
    return Ok("myPolicy work");
}
```

In the Keycloak, create a role (Clients/Roles/Add Role):
[Create Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZItYM.png)

In the Keycloak, create a mapper (Clients/Mapper/Create):
[Create Mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhT5J.png)

In the keycloak, create a service account role for you client (Clients/Service Account Roles):
[Create membership between client and role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071lh.png)

Now it should work :)