# Role based authorization using Keycloak and .NET core

Tags: oauth, .net-core, authorization, keycloak

Having a few minor issues with role based authorization with dotnet core 2.2.3 and Keycloak 4.5.0.

In Keycloak, I've defined a role of 'tester' and a client role 'developer' with appropriate role mappings for an 'admin' user. After authenticating to Keycloak; if I look at the JWT in jwt.io, I can see the following:

```json
{
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "tester"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "template": {
      "roles": [
        "developer"
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

In .NET core, I've tried a bunch of things such as adding `[Authorize(Roles = "tester")]` or `[Authorize(Roles = "developer")]` to my controller method as well as using a policy based authorization where I check `context.User.IsInRole("tester")` inside my `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>` implementation.

If I set some breakpoints in the auth handler. When it gets hit, I can see the 'tester' and 'developer' roles listed as items under the `context.user.Claims` IEnumerable as follows.

```
{realm_access: {"roles":["tester"]}}
{resource_access: {"template":{"roles":["developer"]}}}
```

So I *should* be able to successfully do the authorization in the auth handler by verifying the values for `realm_access` and `resource_access` in the `context.user.Claims` collection, but this would require me to deserialize the claim values, which just seem to be JSON strings.

I'm thinking there has to be better way, or I'm not doing something quite right.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"AspNetCore.Authorization" expects roles in a claim (field) named **"roles"**. And this claim must be an **array of string** (multivalued). You need to make some configuration on Keycloak side.

**The 1st alternative:**

You can change the existing role path.

Go to your Keycloak Admin Console > Client Scopes > roles > Mappers > client roles

- Change "Token Claim Name" as "roles"
- Multivalued: True
- Add to access token: True

**The 2nd alternative:**

If you don't want to touch the existing path, you can create a new Mapper to show the same roles at the root as well.

Go to your Keycloak Admin Console > Client Scopes > roles > Mappers > create

- Name: "root client roles" (or whatever you want)
- Mapper Type: "User Client Role"
- Multivalued: True
- Token Claim Name: "roles"
- Add to access token: True

Comment: Token Claim Name MUST be `role` *not* `roles`

Comment: **The 3nd alternative:** See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817194/10801604

Comment: This worked for me. I used the 2nd alternative, that way the generated token still has the original `"realm_access: { "roles": [...]}` and the new top-level `"roles": [...]"`. Also, I used the plural form for Token Claim Name (roles), not the singular form (role) mentioned by one of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th alternative: read roles from JWT on ticket received event. Here is the the snipet:

```
options.Events.OnTicketReceived = ctx => 
{
   List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties!.GetTokens().ToList();
   ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) ctx.Principal!.Identity!;
                                
   foreach (AuthenticationToken t in tokens)
   {
      claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(t.Name, t.Value));
   }
        
   var access_token = claimsIdentity.FindFirst((claim) => claim.Type == "access_token")?.Value;
        
   var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
   var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(access_token);
   JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jwtSecurityToken.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "resource_access").Value);
   var roleAccess = obj.GetValue("your_client_id")!.ToObject<JObject>()!.GetValue("roles");
   foreach (JToken role in roleAccess!)
   {
      claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.ToString()));
   }
        
   return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In May of 2023, Keycloak introduced a built in [claims transformer](https://github.com/NikiforovAll/keycloak-authorization-services-dotnet/blob/main/src/Keycloak.AuthServices.Authentication/Claims/KeycloakRolesClaimsTransformation.cs). This claims transformer will take the Keycloak roles and transform them into roles that dotnet can understand. It is automatically added in the `AddKeycloakAuthentication` of the [service extensions](https://github.com/NikiforovAll/keycloak-authorization-services-dotnet/blob/main/src/Keycloak.AuthServices.Authentication/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

The key to using it is to properly set your `RolesSource` option within your `KeycloakInstallationOptions` (note, you may be setting this through your `appsettings`). For example,

```cs
builder.Services.AddKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ... Other settings ...
    RolesSource = RolesClaimTransformationSource.Realm,
});
```

It currently defaults to `RolesClaimTransformationSource.ResourceAccess`. For me, the main fix was changing it to the `Realm` options, as that is where my roles where coming from.