# ASP.NET Core does not extract roles from JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

This is a portion of my JWT:

```
{
  "exp": 1681456359,
  "iat": 1681456059,
  "auth_time": 1681453559,
  "jti": "a2c244ab-9069-4192-a798-9d4131962967",
  ...
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-paydar",
      "uma_authorization",
      "Admin",
      "SuperAdmin"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile",
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I have configured roles to be present in JWT in the root level as `realm_access` property.

However, ASP.NET Core does not extract it. This is my C# code:

```
jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnTokenValidated = c =>
    {
        if (c.Principal.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            c.HttpContext.Items["Admin"] = true;
        }
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However, the `c.Principal.IsInRole("Admin")` returns false.

Why is it so? How should I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access Roles in JWT Token .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702555/cant-access-roles-in-jwt-token-net-core)

Comment: I tested your jwtbearerevents code with a user having role "Admin", it goes to true. Could you post your token generate codes?